# Trying to insert or delete columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting:

> Run-time error '1004' subtotal method of Range class failed

I recorded a macro (and manually added a few codes) to copy data, sort it, subtotal it, and to format some of the subtotal lines. The macro works fine when adding rows to the raw data sheet ("StaffingProjected"), but I cannot insert or delete columns. When I do that, I get the error as described in the title.

```
Sub Project()
'
' Project Macro
'

'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Project").Cells.Clear
    Sheets("Project").Cells.RemoveSubtotal
    Sheets("Project").Cells.ClearFormats
    Sheets("Project").Cells.RowHeight = 13.5
    Sheets("StaffingProjected").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Project").Select
    Sheets("Project").Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Project").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Project").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B58") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Project").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:HC58")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=2, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(6, 7, 8, 9, _
        10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, _
        36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, _
        62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, _
        88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110 _
        , 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, _
        130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149 _
        , 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, _
        169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188 _
        , 189, 190, 191, 192, 193), Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData _
        :=True
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2
    Cells.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.RowHeight = 20
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=3
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The debug say the issue is within the "Selection.Subtotal" block. What is the exact issue, and what can I change so that I can delete/insert columns into my raw data sheet ("StaffingProjected")?

Comment: can you please specify at which point(in the code), are you trying to insert/delete column? And what statement are you using to delete?

Answer (score 1):

To my point of view the recorded marco is usefull when you need pieces of code. You should avoid it when you can. Your code will be easier to read and improve.

You can try to add that somewhere in your module :

```
Sub deleteColumnNo(No As Integer)
   Columns(No).EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub

Sub AddColumn(Letter As String)
   Columns(Letter  + ":" + Letter ).Select
   Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
End Sub
```

Then, introduce those lines where you need to delete/add your column :

```
Sub Project()
  '[...]
  CleanColumnNo 1  'delete the first column
  CleanColumnNo 2  'delete the second column
  AddColumn "B"    'add a column between A and B 
  '[...]
end sub
```

Anyway don't hesitate to add additional information next time, you will have better answers.

Have a nice day!